# phpstan not pass over strip_tags

Tags: php, strip-tags, phpstan

i have string of html which i want to explode by `<br>`, but sometimes it can be inside of other tags.

```
if (in_array($param, $customOrdering, true) && $value) {
    $ordering = array_search($param, $customOrdering, true);
    $segments[$ordering] = [];
    if (in_array($param, $explodeParams, true)) {
        $values = explode('<br>', $value);
        foreach ($values as $v) {
            $testing_value = $v;
            if (!empty(trim(strip_tags($testing_value)))) {
                array_push($segments[$ordering], $this->createSegmentFromParam($param, $v));
138         } elseif (!empty(trim($v)) && $segments[$ordering]) {
139             end($segments[$ordering])->value_raw .= strip_tags($v, $this->allowedTags);
            }
        }
    } else {
        array_push($segments[$ordering], $this->createSegmentFromParam($param, $value));
    }
}
```

declaration of createSegmentFormParam

```
 @return ArrayHash
 
private function createSegmentFromParam($param, $value)
```

and i have this output from phpStan

```
 138    Right side of && is always false.                                    
 139    Cannot access property $value_raw on false.
```

any ideas how to pass on ? code working well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is still an open issue for similar behaviour or PHP Stan - [False negative with array_push on property](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/2888)

Try not using `array_push` and replace it on line `138` with the following:

```php
$segments[$ordering][] = $this->createSegmentFromParam($param, $v);
```

Apart from this in the beginning of your code `array_search` may return `FALSE` you do want to check this before going further down the code...

Comment: about array_search i think that it shouldnt be false as at line before i testing it by in_array with same parameters